# Not able to connect to a simple stream from CSI camera to network

Tags: raspicam, streaming-video, vlc, h264, rtsp

I have been battling with motioneye in all manner of configurations, and wanted a simple solution until the python3 branch becomes stable (hopefully with support for the pi CSI module).

I was wondering if I could basically stream the output of the `libcamera-vid` command to some backend (like frigate or a central motioneye installation)

I have reinstalled Bookworm several times, so on a clean bookworm lite (no gui) image for raspberry pi 4 (8gb) I ran `libcamera-vid --height 1080 --width 1920 -t 0 --inline --listen -o tcp://0.0.0.0:8081`

```
jss@picam004:~ $ libcamera-vid --height 1080 --width 1920 -t 0 --inline --listen -o tcp://0.0.0.0:8081
[0:31:28.609834164] [1158]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:284 libcamera v0.1.0+118-563cd78e
[0:31:28.660775733] [1161]  WARN RPiSdn sdn.cpp:39 Using legacy SDN tuning - please consider moving SDN inside rpi.denoise
[0:31:28.663423182] [1161]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:444 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 to Unicam device /dev/media4 and ISP device /dev/media1
[0:31:28.663557682] [1161]  INFO RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1142 Using configuration file '/usr/share/libcamera/pipeline/rpi/vc4/rpi_apps.yaml'
```

I went to VLC and pointed it to `http://192.168.1.235:8081`

[image: vlc dialog]

As soon as I click "play" the console writes some lines:

```
Made DRM preview window
Mode selection for 1920:1080:12:P
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,640x480/0 - Score: 6093.33
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,1296x972/0 - Score: 3797.33
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,1920x1080/0 - Score: 1000
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,2592x1944/0 - Score: 2717.33
Stream configuration adjusted
[0:32:29.392592668] [1158]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1183 configuring streams: (0) 1920x1080-YUV420 (1) 1920x1080-SGBRG10_CSI2P
[0:32:29.393092462] [1161]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:608 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 1920x1080-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1920x1080-pGAA
```

Nothing is displayed in the VLC window. However on the attached monitor of the PI, the video image is displayed.
If I click stop on the VLC application, the command terminates.
Where am I going wrong? Or am I barking up a wrong tree?

if I disconnect the monitor from the pi I am spammed with loads of lines of

```
#<seq> (31.85 fps) exp 33167.00 ag 8.00 dg 1.00

I also tried with `libcamera-vid --height 480 --width 640 -t 0 --inline --listen -o tcp://0.0.0.0:8081` with basically the same experience
```